# Playlist isn't playing songs

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my problem, I'm trying to just display the name of the file I wish to play, but when I did that my playlist just skips past the song and doesn't actually play it. I have no idea why it's doing this. So my question is, How can I display the song names so they actually play?

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MusicalCloud.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Musical Cloud" Height="400" Width="600">
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="Play" Source="Images/play.png" />
    <Image x:Key="Pause" Source="Images/pause.png" />
    <Image x:Key="Muted" Source="Images/volume_0.png" />
    <Image x:Key="Low" Source="Images/volume_low.png" />
    <Image x:Key="High" Source="Images/volume_high.png" />
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <Grid Background="DarkGray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="85*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="musicFinder"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0">
            <ListBox x:Name="playlist"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FileList}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMedia}">
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlayer"
                    Margin="3"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                    MediaEnded="Player_MediaEnded"
                    MediaOpened="Player_MediaOpened"
                    MediaFailed="Player_MediaEnded"
                    Source="{Binding CurrentMedia}">
        </MediaElement>

        <Grid x:Name="mediaControls"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="playPauseButton"
                    Margin="3"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Click="PlayPause">
                <DynamicResource ResourceKey="Play" />
            </Button>

        </Grid>

        </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace MusicalCloud
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer timer;

    public delegate void timerTick();
    timerTick tick;

    string sec, min, hours;
    string[] result;
    private bool mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
    private bool userIsDraggingSlider = false;
    public ObservableCollection<string> FileList { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Donald Rohlman\Dropbox\Music");
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void GetFiles(string folderPath)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath).Select(path => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)).ToArray();
        FileList = new ObservableCollection<string>(files);
    }

    private void PlayPause(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (playPauseButton.Content == FindResource("Play"))
        {
            mediaPlayer.Play();
            mediaPlayerIsPlaying = true;
            playPauseButton.Content = FindResource("Pause");
        }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer.Pause();
            mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
            playPauseButton.Content = FindResource("Play");
        }
    }

    private void Player_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentSongIndex = FileList.IndexOf(SelectedMedia);
        currentSongIndex++;
        if (currentSongIndex < FileList.Count)
        {
            SelectedMedia = FileList[currentSongIndex] as string;
            Play();
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentMedia = null;
        }
    }

    private void Player_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaPlayerIsPlaying = true;
    }

    void Play(string media = null)
    {
        mediaPlayer.Stop();
        mediaPlayerIsPlaying = false;
        CurrentMedia = media ?? SelectedMedia;
        PlayPause(null, null);
    }

    public string CurrentMedia
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CurrentMediaProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentMediaProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentMedia.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentMediaProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentMedia", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string SelectedMedia
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedMediaProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedMediaProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedMedia.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedMediaProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedMedia", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) => (s as MainWindow).Play()));

}
}
```

Comment: Play calls Stop, then calls PlayPause which calls Play, which calls Stop, then calls PlayPause, then calls Pause.... etc...

Comment: But before I added the line of code to just get the filename, it worked as intended. But after adding that bit of code, it started to do this. Would that still be the issue?

Comment: I suggest that you create a **minimal** example. Remove *everything* that is not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just went through and made it more minimal while still making the same error.

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint in PlayPause, click Play and step through the code?